# Graph of kinetic energy of ejected electron vs intensity

Tags: photochemistry, atomic-structure

While studying photoelectric effect I got a doubt in the graph of kinetic energy of ejected electron vs the intensity of electromagnetic radiation.
Everywhere this graph is given as
[image]

But here for 0 intensity, a certain value of kinetic energy is given but 0 intensity means no light is falling so how can kinetic energy of ejected electron can have a value other than zero. As per me the graph should start from origin and then suddenly or drastically rise with infinite slope(with increase in intensity) to a point which is kinetic energy for that particular frequency. Or is it like that zero intensity does not mean no light instead it means negligible light. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Poutnik Does that mean that at 0 KE point, we are talking about the electron's that energy that it has being bound within the atom instead of being as photoelectron?

Comment: But if we have 0 persons we can't take any value of height I think. We would simply take for 0 persons height is 0 as it cannot be measured. Similarly for 0 ejected electrons kinetic energy of ejected electron should be zero as it cannot be measured.

Comment: I suspect that, mathematically speaking, you are correct. But most people reproducing the chart leave out the subtlety that it is valid only for any *positive* value of intensity and meaningless at zero. But a careful mathematician would *not* show a *line* from zero to the ke for that frequency but a single point at zero and a flat line for any positive value of intensity.

Comment: Clearly if there are no photons then nothing happens, so the graph starts at an intensity equivalent to 1 photon.

Answer (score 2):

You use zero with 2 different meanings and confuse them together. Zero as value of physical quantity and zero as arbitrary qualitative symbol for missing measurement. If you could not measure temperature, it does not mean $T = \pu{0 K}$. Missing measurement would be marked by a dash or similar, not by $\pu{0 K}$.

---

Zero energy has no special meaning for emitted electrons that are not here.
$$\lim_{n \to 0+}{(\frac {E_\mathrm{em}}n)} \ne 0$$
$$\lim_{n \to 0+}{(\frac {E_\mathrm{em}}n)} = E_\mathrm{1e}$$

where

- $E_\mathrm{em}$ is the total energy of emitted electrons
- $n$ is the number of emitted electrons
- $E_\mathrm{1e}$ id the energy of 1 emitted electron

If the total energy of emitted electrons is zero, it does not mean the energy per electron is zero. Because you divide zero by zero, what has not particular general value, what you learn when learning mathematical limits. Some ratios with both terms converging to zero converge to zero, others converge to either infinity and yet other converge to finite numbers.

Comment: I think applying the uncertainty principle, we can say there always will be at least one photoelectron and hence a non-zero KE. Is it correct to say?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the uncertainty principle. Rather, the intensity is never zero. but even if is,  still  $\frac 00 \ne  0$